# Restoring the mouse movement settings

Tags: macos, mouse

I have a Microsoft laser mouse, which was nice and smooth in OS X, until I installed IntelliPoint for OS X in an attempt to make the scroll wheel nicer. The result is I hate the mouse movement/tracking now, no matter what I set the speed to in the settings it's horrible. I uninstalled IntelliPoint, but it made no change.

I noticed if I log on to my Mac as a different user, the mouse settings are fine (like they used to be). Is there a way to restore them back on my account, such as by editing some files or whatever?

Comment: Did you run the uninstaller application or remove `/System/Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext`?